# Logical operations using Named Ranges within Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010, boolean-logic, named-ranges

I came across this issue when trying to use better named referenced in my spreadsheet

Take this example using Boolean logic

[image]

Column A has the named range "Include1"
Column B has the named range "Include2"

The formulas are:

[image]

What I see is that if I use the named range directly it picks up the value but when I include it within a Boolean comparision (AND, OR) then it does not work.
(Column F and I should match just like Column G and J)

Am I doing something wrong or is this a known issue?
If I am doing something wrong how would I get the Boolean comparrisions to work with named ranges?

--EDIT

I just found out that having the following works:

```
=AND(Include1=TRUE, Include2=TRUE)
=OR(Include1=TRUE, Include2=TRUE)
```

This is not too intuitive but is this by design of excel?

Comment: `AND` and `OR` functions accept ranges as parameters, so if the named ranges are columns, then it takes all logical values from those columns. When the parameter is: `Include1=TRUE` it evaluates only current row when you enter it as normal formula, and again all values if you enter it as array formula (Ctrl+Shif+Enter).

Comment: Makes sense... If you put it as an answer I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Description of `AND` function ([MS link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AND-function-c192b0d8-0eeb-4768-a674-f84e6df9aefb)):

> Syntax
>
> AND(logical1, [logical2], ...)
>
> The AND function syntax has the following arguments:
>
> logical1    Required. The first condition that you want to test that
>   can evaluate to either TRUE or FALSE.
>
> logical2, ...    Optional. Additional conditions that you want to test
>   that can evaluate to either TRUE or FALSE, up to a maximum of 255
>   conditions.
>
> Remarks
>
> The arguments must evaluate to logical values, such as TRUE or FALSE,
>   **or the arguments must be arrays** or references that contain logical
>   values.
>
> If an array or reference argument contains text or empty cells, those
>   values are ignored.

This means that:

```
=AND(Inlude1)
```

calculates logical `AND` of all cells (except text and empty) in column `A`.

In the second version:

```
=AND(Include1=True)
```

The parameter is an array, only in an array formula (confirmed with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`). The same formula confirmed with `Enter` takes only the value from current row in column `A`. The same rule applies for `OR` function and multiple named ranges.